# Create model based on another model attributes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say i have 2 models **Quote** and **Invoice** and they share common fields. How do you convert a Quote to an Invoice. How would that work around the models and controllers with creating a new Invoice based on the values already stored in the Invoice?

Comment: Look into STI in the rails doc, or make Quote and invoice a state of a single model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think i will go with the second option,  seems to integrate better with the flow of the app.

Comment: You might consider pulling the common attributes out into another model that both Quote and Invoice have a relationship with. That way your different models (Quote and Invoice) can be separate entities entirely with some shared attributes and you can easily make one from the other by sharing the associated model.